# Room Primary Key Autogenerate multiple Columns

Tags: android

my Current Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "cells",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Table::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("tableId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Column::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("columnId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ],
    indices = [Index(value=["id", "tableId"]), Index(value=["id", "tableId", "columnId"],  unique = true)]
)
data class Cell(
    val tableId: Long,
    val columnId: Long,
    val value: String,
    val type: String


) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long = 0
}
```

Each Cell has its own Unique ID, but that is not what i want

i want my PrimaryKey to be made up out of `"id", "tableId", "columnId"`
Id should be autogenerated and it should be possible to have the same id multiple times.
just the combination of these 3 fields should be unique
`Index(value=["id", "tableId", "columnId"], unique = true)`

```
2020-01-28 12:34:11.228 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=1, tableId=1, columnId=1, value='-5.55', type='€')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.229 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=2, tableId=1, columnId=1, value='+1.23', type='€')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.229 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=3, tableId=1, columnId=1, value='-10.10', type='€')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.231 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=4, tableId=1, columnId=2, value='Ausgabe A', type='String')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.231 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=5, tableId=1, columnId=2, value='Einnahme X', type='String')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.232 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=6, tableId=1, columnId=2, value='Ausgabe B', type='String')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.232 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=7, tableId=1, columnId=1, value='12', type='€')
2020-01-28 12:34:11.232 de.hsos.ma.adhocdb E/ERRROR: CELL: Cell(id=8, tableId=1, columnId=2, value='45', type='€')
```

[image]

Each Row Should have the same `ID`

How could i achieve a Primarykey out of 3 Columns, where one Column (`ID`) is still autogenerated?